# Reuse index transformer expressions fails on Id

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I'm looking to be able to reuse some of the transform expressions from indexes so I can perform identical transformations in my service layer when the document is already available.

For example, whether it's by a query or by transforming an existing document at the service layer, I want to produce a ViewModel object with this shape:

```
public class ClientBrief
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    // ellided
}
```

From this document model:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public CompleteName Name { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<EmailAddressKey, EmailAddress> Emails { get; private set; }
    // ellided
}

public class CompleteName
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public enum EmailAddressKey
{
    EmailAddress1,
    EmailAddress2,
    EmailAddress3
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RoutingType { get; set; }
}
```

I have an expression to transform a full Client document to a ClientBrief view model:

```
    static Expression<Func<IClientSideDatabase, Client, ClientBrief>> ClientBrief = (db, client) =>
        new ClientBrief
        {
            Id = client.Id,
            FullName = client.Name.FullName,
            Email = client.Emails.Select(x => x.Value.Address).FirstOrDefault()
            // ellided
        };
```

This expression is then manipulated using an expression visitor so it can be used as the TransformResults property of an index (Client_Search) which, once it has been generated at application startup, has the following definition in Raven Studio:

Map:

```
docs.Clients.Select(client => new {
    Query = new object[] {
        client.Name.FullName,
        client.Emails.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Address.Split(new char[] {
            '@'
        })) // ellided
    }
})
```

(The `Query` field is analysed.)

Transform:

```
results.Select(result => new {
    result = result,
    client = Database.Load(result.Id.ToString())
}).Select(this0 => new {
    Id = this0.client.__document_id,
    FullName = this0.client.Name.FullName,
    Email = DynamicEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(this0.client.Emails.Select(x => x.Value.Address))
})
```

However, the transformation expression used to create the index can then also be used in the service layer locally when I already have a Client document:

```
var brief = ClientBrief.Compile().Invoke(null, client);
```

It allows me to only have to have one piece of code that understands the mapping from Client to ClientBrief, whether that code is running in the database or the client app.  It all seems to work ok, except the query results all have an Id of `0`.

**How can I get the Id property (integer) properly populated in the query?**

I've read a number of similar questions here but none of the suggested answers seem to work. (Changing the Ids to strings from integers is not an option.)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something, but why you pass `IClientSideDatabase` to expression when you pass `Client` also?

Comment: From your code it is not obvious why `client.Id` would be `0`. Is it `> 0` when you query it otherwise? Further: this is AutoMapper or ValueInjecter were made for. Don't these tool suit you?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, IClientSideDatabase is passed in the same way that it is passed into a TransformResult delegate - so the transformation can load additional documents if required.

Comment: @GertArnold, I suspect it is because __document_id is a string and something somewhere is choking when it tries to move a dynamically typed string like 'clients/34' into an integer.

Comment: You show the class and expression, then jump to a translation of an index transform.  Can you show how you used the expression the transform?  Even better, link to a gist of a failing unit test so I can reproduce your results.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have expanded the code to show all that seems relevant. I haven't show the expression visitor stuff because it's a bit convoluted but it's not really relevant. It produces the same output as if I had simply assigned a local delegate in the index constructor. Effectively it becomes the code shown in the second Select() of the Transform.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time following your sample fully,  Really the best way to dig in to this would be with a failing self-contained unit test.

Nonetheless, let's see if I can pull out the important bits.

In the transform, you have two areas where you are working with the id:

```
...
client = Database.Load(result.Id.ToString())
...
Id = this0.client.__document_id,
...
```

The `result.Id` in the first line and the `Id =` in the second line are expected to be integers.

The `Database.Load()` expects a string document key and that is also what you see in `__document_id`.

The confusion comes from Raven's documentation, code, and examples all use the terms *id* and *key* interchangeably, but this is *only* true when you use string identifiers.  When you use non-string identifiers, such as ints or guids, the *id* may be `123`, but the document key is still `clients/123`.

So try changing your transform so it translates:

```
...
client = Database.Load("clients/" + result.Id)
...
Id = int.Parse(this0.client.__document_id.Split("/")[1]),
...
```

... or whatever the c# equivalent linq form would be.